# Override copy or copyWithZone: or both?

Tags: iphone, nscopying

I'm confused looking at Apple's documentation and reading through Cocoa design patterns.  In the Apple documentation for `copyWithZone:`, it reads:

> This method exists so class objects can be used in situations where
>   you need an object that conforms to the NSCopying protocol. For
>   example, this method lets you use a class object as a key to an
>   NSDictionary object. You should not override this method.

For `copy` it reads:

> This is a convenience method for classes that adopt the NSCopying
>   protocol. An exception is raised if there is no implementation for
>   copyWithZone:.
>
> NSObject does not itself support the NSCopying protocol. Subclasses
>   must support the protocol and implement the copyWithZone: method. A
>   subclass version of the copyWithZone: method should send the message
>   to super first, to incorporate its implementation, unless the subclass
>   descends directly from NSObject.

In the examples in Cocoa Design Patterns, they override `copyWithZone:` and `mutableCopyWithZone:` but do not override `copy` when conforming to the `NSCopying` protocol.  Is that what I should do if I want to use my custom subclass in an `NSDictionary` as a key?

Or do I override `copy`?

Similarly, if I do `[myClass copy]`, does that call `copyWithZone:` or `copy` for that my custom subclass? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

It's pretty simple: the default implementation of `copy` just calls `copyWithZone:` with a NULL argument. So you should always implement `copyWithZone:`. However, since memory zones are not used (as far as I know) on iOS, you should ignore the zone without making any assumptions.

Edit: to elaborate, you *may* implement `copy` as well, but you *must* implement `copyWithZone:` because you never know which of them `NSDictionary` will call in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using the superclass convenience method as it is, because it does nothing but call `copyWithZone:` in any case.

This should be true for any convenience method. You should find out what method they call and override that instead.

Also as said above, zones are no longer used at all but the method still has that parameter for compatibility and historical reasons.